# Mongoose bulk update multiple docs with different values – use timestamps and discriminator

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a schema that has both timestamps and discriminator key options set. Using `Model.save()`, everything works fine, but using `Model.bulkWrite` neither my discriminator key nor the timestamps get saved/updated.

Is there a way in mongoose to bulk update documents (each with different values) and to maintain the behaviour regarding schema options like in `Model.save()`?

My use case is that I have about 500 documents and I have to check for each if the document already exists (if so update parts of it) it and if not insert a complete new record. This works fine with `bulkWrite` and an array of `updateOne` operations except that the schema options do not work.